# Iterate over df and add rows based on logic - python

Tags: python, pandas

Given the df created by the python code below, I need to loop through the df and add a row for any month in between the start date and end date.

Create df

```
import pandas as pd
inp = [
    {'subject':1, 'start':"2016-11-01", 'end':"2017-03-01" },
    {'subject':2, 'start':"2016-12-01", 'end':"2017-05-01" },
]
df = pd.DataFrame(inp)
df
```

[image: image of original vs desired df]

Comment: It will be useful if the OP includes what you have done to achieve this.

Comment: The output was structured manually for illustration. Record by record in the input, a row was added to the output, iterating months, until the start date was equal to the end date.